# Problem with WordTables building in UIMA RUTA / RETAINTYPE not working

Tags: uima, ruta

I am trying to annotate a document with RUTA but not all of the terms in my dictionary are firing. It appears that the wordtables may not be reading in properly or that RETAINTYPE(SPACE)/RETAINTYPE(WS) is not working.

Example: I have the terms "open cupboard", "opens cupboard", and "opening cupboard" in  a csv. I read in the terms to RUTA and read in the proper column but when I analyze a document only "open account" will annotate.

I have tried using RETAINTYPE(SPACE) and RETAINTYPE(WS) to fix the problem but to no success.

Additionally if I add the term "ope cupboard" to my csv that reads into my wordtable then "ope cupboard" will be the only phrase that fires when I build my annotation. I'm led to believe that the wordtable may not be reading in properly and filtering out these similar longer phrases that all begin the same and end the same. the phrase "open the door" does annotate correctly when in the same csv as the previous mentioned terms but it has a different ending. Once I add "opens the door" to the same csv as it does not annotate "opens the door" and will only fire on "open the door"

Phrases that are only one word long ex: "opencupboard", "openscupboard", fire properly when I do not use RETAINTYPE(SPACE) when analyzing the document, but I need to be able to retain the space because of other shorter phrases that are causing me too many false positives.

I have also recreated this problem with other phrases.

Basically I am unable to annotate lemmas.

Comment: The problem normally is caused by the fact that the csv contains whitespaces which can lead to different lookup paths in the trie. Try to remove the whitespaces in the dictionary file.

Answer (score 2):

In the wordtable implementation the whitespaces are ignored by default. So "hello world" will be indexed as "helloworld".

Analysing content by RUTA also ignores whitespaces by default. So "hello world" in a document will be recognized, but also "helloworld", "he llo wo rld" are matches.

If the whitespaces are important in your context you can configure the wordtable to use the whitespaces when indexing. This can be done by passing a configuration parameter (PARAM_DICT_REMOVE_WS = false) to the engine. Of course make them also visible in the RUTA scripts itself before executing the MARKTABLE action by the following action "ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);".

In RUTA 2.6.1 (current version) there are some issues with the wordtables. There are some fixes but not yet patched.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/UIMA/issues/UIMA-5752
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/UIMA/issues/UIMA-5775

If the configuration with 2.6.1 not work you could try to get the latest 2.6.1 sources and apply the patches on it. Maybe that's solve your issue.

Comment: Hopefully the patch works because my engine was already configured to not remove ws when building and I already had RETAINTYPE(WS) built in, it appears that RUTA is deleting similar entries as I noted with the example listed in the question.

Comment: Sorry, Jasper, I missed to apply the patches. I will do so asap.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKluegl